# Validar solo nro y letras en JAVA

Tags: java, array

Necesito ayuda para que no me permita ingresar otra letra que no sea F o M y tampoco otro nro me que no sea 1 o 2
pensaba hacerlo con un bucle while pero necesito ayuda en la condición del bucle, podrian ayudarme porfavor?
Esta seria la parte del codigo que tengo

```
for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
           String s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba F si es mujer o M si es hombre");
           char sexo= Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));
           String p=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Usted trabaja?"+ "Responda 1 si trabaja o 2 si no");
           int rta= Integer.parseInt(p);}
```

Comment: Usá el operador lógico _or_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrias hacer uso de un [do while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) con el operador logico [AND](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-6957/chp-typeopexpr-6/index.html) para que te vuelva a solicitar un dato correcto cada que ingreses uno incorrecto o en este caso diferente a los valores que requieres

```
char sexo=' ';
int rta=0;
for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
           do{ 
           String s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba F si es mujer o M si es hombre");
           sexo= Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));
           }while(sexo!='F' && sexo!='M');
           do{
           String p=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Usted trabaja?"+ "Responda 1 si trabaja o 2 si no");
           rta= Integer.parseInt(p);
           }while(rta!=1 && rta!=2);
       }
```