# Podria alguien a solucionar este error de excepciones, me gustaría saber que esta mal

Tags: java, maven

Me gustaria saber como puedo solucionar este error, el bloque donde se ejecuta el primer bucle do while lo hace sin problemas pero cuando le doy datos String al segundo me resulta en este error

```
**Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project Trabajo: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
**
```

#### Código

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Datos a[] = new Datos[1];
        Datos datos = new Datos();
        char sexo;
        int rta = 0;
        
        //CARGA DE DATOS
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            do {
                String s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba F si es mujer o M si es hombre");
                sexo= Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));
            } while(sexo != 'F' && sexo != 'M');
            
            try {
                do {
                    String p=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Usted trabaja?" + "Responda 1 si trabaja o 2 si no");
                    rta= Integer.parseInt(p);
                } while(rta != 1 && rta != 2);
            } catch(InputMismatchException ex){ 
                //al ingresar una letra se para la ejecución               
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe ingresa obligatoriamente un nro", "ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si te sirvio la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/518498/validar-solo-nro-y-letras-en-java) da click en el check-in ✓

Comment: No entiendo cómo obtienes una excepción Maven de ese código. Si estás construyendo un proyecto, por favor ve a [edit] y añade una traza más completa del error. Puedes usar `mvn -X clean install` o el comando que sea que usas con la opción -X para un debug más detallado. De cualquier forma, sé más claro sobre cómo estás corriendo ese código y así sabremos cómo se relaciona con el error que refieres